# Pre-approved/Subcriptions Payments in Adaptive payments in PHP

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am really struggling a lot with the steps of "HOW TO DEDUCT MONEY WHEN A USER PRE-APPROVED/SUBSCRIBED" and the same amount of money will get deducted every month of the year that the user has subscribed.

For Example, In Renting process for a property.

And i also got to know that adaptive payment in paypal supports monthly subscription ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a call to the Preapproval API to create the preapproval profile and get the preapproval key.

Then you can make calls to the Pay API using the preapproval key and the money will be transferred immediately without further approval at that point.

So in your case you would need to put together a cron job or something on the server that would automatically pull payments that should be made each day and hit the Pay API for each one.

Comment: Ok i got it. Thanks !